# A FEX port remains inactive - how can I bring it up?

Tags: cisco, cisco-nexus-2000

When implementing Cisco Nexus 5k switches (5596UP), I connected a server to a dual homed 2000 FEX (2232T), the port belonging to a virtual port channel. However, the port changed the status from *notconnected* to *inactive* and remained so.

- I verified that speed and duplex match, i.e. auto/auto, tested also 1000/full.
- I verified that the corresponding VLAN exists and is the access VLAN on this port.
- Default port settings, except this access VLAN.

What may be wrong, and how can I correct it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turned out, that the configuration of this port did not match on both Nexus 5k, as I configured just one switch at first.

- I configured the port on the second Nexus switch in the same way.
- I plan to implement the config sync feature so that issue should not happen again.

Once the configuration of the ports of the virtual port channel matched, the link came up.

Comment: I single-home my 2Ks (and dual-home end hosts to a pair of 2Ks) for just this reason. It's a pain to ensure the upstream devices are always in sync.

Comment: Be really careful with config-sync. We had it running here and eventually removed it because it was so bad. We just ended up automating the configuration of host ports to automatically apply the configuration to both 5k's. We found this to be much more preferable than config-sync. Make sure you do your lab work and homework before doing it. They say it's better now, so maybe some of the issues have been fixed.